# nmake or makefile cannot find directory

Tags: visual-studio, makefile, tbb, nmake

Hello I'm trying to build intel's tbb (threaded building blocks) from source. I have downloaded and extracted the source. I point visual studio's command prompt to the directory of extraction, where there is a makefile. I have edited the tbb_root variable inside the make file to point at the extracted directory, but when I tried running it I get

> Makefile(28) : fatal error U1052: file '$(tbb_root)/build/common.inc'
>   not found Stop.

Lines 27 and 28 of the make file are as follows (all previous lines are comments/whitespace)

```
tbb_root=c:/tbb_extract/tbb42_20140122oss
include $(tbb_root)/build/common.inc
```

I have verified that c:/tbb_extract/tbb42_20140122oss/build/common.inc exists, so why does this fellow not make!

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple one - the file seems to of been assembled a kind of half GNU half VS-style makefile. It was a cannibalisation and I don't think it was ever tested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use GNU make in order to build TBB from sources; nmake is not supported, and never was.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `nmake` but according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y32zxwh.aspx) it doesn't use `include` to include files.  Try using `!INCLUDE` instead.

Comment: Didn't seem to work unfortunately, generated:
./build/common.inc(28) : fatal error U1034: syntax error : separator missing
Stop.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  I don't think I've ever used nmake in my life.  The docs are available, or you can download GNU make for Windows (Google can help) and use that instead.

Comment: The answer was simple one - the file seems to of been assembled a kind of half GNU half VS-style makefile. It was a cannibalisation and I don't think it was ever tested. Thanks for your help anyway :)